# System.Collections.ObjectModel Collection<T>

Tags: c#, collections

I have this class that I'm trying to understand:

```
public class Track 
{ 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public uint Length { get; set; } 
    public Album Album { get; internal set; } 
} 

public class Album : Collection<Track> 
{ 
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Track item) 
    { 
        base.InsertItem(index, item); 
        item.Album = this; 
    } 

protected override void SetItem(int index, Track item) 
{ 
    base.SetItem(index, item); 
    item.Album = this; 
} 

protected override void RemoveItem(int index) 
{ 
    this[index].Album = null;
   base.RemoveItem(index); 
} 

protected override void ClearItems() 
{ 
    foreach (Track track in this) 
    { 
        track.Album = null; 
    } 
    base.ClearItems(); 
} 
}
```

Why we using base.InsertItem, while after assigning 
new variable?Will it be ok to omit base.InsertItem and other
(set, remove, clear items).

---

I suppose I wasn't clear enough about my question.

base.InsertItem in my opinion it is Collections method
that adds item to the collection. So if we've already 
added it why we are assigning this to the item.Album.

I'm a little confused about Album that is in the Track
class and Album class that is using Collection .

Can someone show me example of using this collection?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this method override:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, Track item)
{ 
    base.InsertItem(index, item); 
    item.Album = this; 
}
```

This changes [the behavior of the `InsertItem` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132412.aspx) that was inherited from the base class `Collection<Track>`. The first line calls the implementation from the base class. So after that, we have done the same as the base class would do. The second line modifies the item being inserted by providing a reference to the current collection (`Album`).

It is not clear what you ask, but suppose you did this instead:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, Track item)
{ 
    InsertItem(index, item);    // bad
    item.Album = this; 
}
```

That would not be a good idea, because now the method calls itself recursively *ad infinitum*. So that is not an option.

Suppose you did instead this:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, Track item)
{ 
    item.Album = this; 
}
```

Now, the **only** thing the `InsertItem` method does is write the `Album` to the `item`. Nothing is actually inserted in the underlying collection. This is probably not what you want.

---

So what is the `base` keyword for? It allows you to call the method (or other member) of the base class even if the method was overridden of hidden on the current class. Your example gives the typical use of the `base` access.

Answer (score 1):

> Why we using `base.InsertItem`, while after assigning new variable?

`Track` is a `class`, so it has reference-type semantics. That means, you can assign to its `Album` property before, after, whenever - it doesn't really matter, because it exists on the managed heap, and everything else is just a reference to it.

What you've shown is a common idiom - you add the `Track` to an `Album` (which is a `Collection` of `Tracks`), and then you set a "back reference": you set the `Track`'s `Album` property to be the `Album` you just added it to.

Note, they do the assignment in question *after* `InsertItem` is called, because that's the correct order of events. The item isn't part of the collection until after it has been added. Also notice that the `RemoveItem` override does it in the opposite order.

> Will it be ok to omit `base.InsertItem` and other (set, remove, clear items).

You tell me - it depends on how you plan on using the code. What you've shown is a simple strongly-typed collection, that manages the "container references" of the items you add to that collection. It is a common format used all throughout the `Windows.Forms` code, for example.

Comment: I would say leave in the `base` calls, as you want the default collection methods to run.  The only thing he could change at this point would be to remove the back references and do those throughout his code (which the example tries to simplify).  I'd say leave it as-is unless you develop a different tech approach that you want to implement.  You can't do that until you understand what the current code does and why.

Comment: @ps2goat I would call the `base` calls essential - remove them and the collection stores nothing (unless you remove the overrides of course).

Comment: @Johnathon Reinhart, I knew you would.  I was just adding commentary for the poster to think about.